# Why is the analyzer defined globally in Zend.Search.Lucene?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I just noticed that the Zend lucene implementation has a default analyzer that can be modified using [`Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Search_Lucene/Analysis/Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer.html#setDefault), but I couldn't find a way to override that default when performing a query. Do I really need to reset the *default* analyzer if I'm working on multiple indexes or am I missing a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original Java API for Lucene, `QueryParser` takes an `analyzer` argument. I'm not sure why they decided to use a global variable in Zend Framework, but apparently setting the analyzer globally is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the TextNum analyzer because the default (`Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive`) doesn't allow searching by integers.

To override the default, I run:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum());
```